# .htaccess file for forums

Tags: .htaccess

I need to write an .htcaccess file that will meet the following conditions:

1) redirect *site.com* to *www.site.com*

2) redirect *site.com/forum/index.php* to *www.site.com/forum* (no trailing slash)

3) redirect *site.com/forum/* to *www.site.com/forum* (no trailing slash)

4) redirect *site.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page* to *site.com/wiki* (no trailing slash)*

5) redirect all 404s to *site.com*

Additionally, I need a second version of .htaccess for temporary use that will meet the conditions above with the following modifications

*6) redirect *site.com* or *www.site.com* to *www.site.com/forum* (no trailing slash)

*7) redirect all 404s to *www.site.com/forum* (no trailing slash)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Version 1:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# 1) redirect site.com to www.site.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

# 2) redirect site.com/forum/index.php to www.site.com/forum (no trailing slash)
# 3) redirect site.com/forum/ to www.site.com/forum (no trailing slash)
RewriteRule ^forum/(index.php)?$ forum [L]

# 4) redirect *site.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page* to site.com/wiki (no trailing slash)*
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^wiki/index\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^title=Main_Page$
RewriteRule .* wiki [L]

# 5) redirect all 404s to site.com
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Version 2:

```
# 6) redirect site.com or www.site.com to www.site.com/forum (no trailing slash)
RedirectMatch ^/$ http://www.site2.com/forum

# 7) redirect all 404s to www.site.com/forum (no trailing slash)
ErrorDocument 404 forum
```

Comment: That line should have been `RewriteRule ^forum/(index.php)?$ forum [L]` (note the opening/closing parentheses). Sorry for the typo

Comment: Additionally, the 3 lines added for the wiki redirect don't seem to do anything.  The URL still resolves to /wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: I added the closing parentheses, and now I get a 310 error when accessing the forum.   This webpage has a redirect loop
The webpage at /forum/ has resulted in too many redirects. Clearing your cookies for this site or allowing third-party cookies may fix the problem. If not, it is possibly a server configuration issue and not a problem with your computer.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
Learn more about this problem.
Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.

Comment: Does "forum" folder exist? because if so, then "/forum" without trailing slash will be automatically rewritten by apache into "/forum/" and then it will hit the loop. the rules you asked for only make sense if those locations are not physical anymore

Comment: Yes, the forum folder is where the forum is installed, but I wanted it without the trailing slash for SEO purposes.  Is this possible?

Comment: Also, the line
ErrorDocument 404 forum simply prints the word forum on the screen.

Comment: To clarify, I only want the trailing slash hidden from the main page, i.e. /forum/index.php.  In all other cases, for example, forum/topic.html, the slash must stay of course.

Comment: You can't hide it from the user (as far as i know). if it's a folder it's gonna have the trailing slash

Comment: As for ErrorDocument, you might need to add slash before 'forum' (ie `ErrorDocument 404 /forum` .. that directive falls back to plaintext

Comment: This is what I get after adding the slash before 'forum.'  The requested URL /asdf was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 301 Moved Permanently error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: ouch ;) what about `ErrorDocument 404 /forum/` ? ;) (there is an internal redirect to add trailing slash that apache does)

Comment: that SORT OF works.  it redirects to the forum but it strips the forum's skin and displays bare content without CSS.  that usually happens when there is an extra character in the URL, like a slash or a question mark that shouldn't be there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13063/discussion-between-knocks-x-and-poncha)

Comment: Hi I'm having problems with that .htaccess again.  Opened a new question -- stackoverflow.com/questions/11589061 -- can you please take a look?  Thanks!